# Binary operator ’==’ cannot be applied to two struct operands

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a 3rd party framework, there is a file contains the following code:

```
struct AdServiceType {
    init(_ value: UInt)
    var value: UInt
}
var Internal: AdServiceType { get }
var Normal: AdServiceType { get }
var External: AdServiceType { get }

class AdService : NSObject {
   var serviceType: AdServiceType
   init!()
}
```

Then, in my own project class, I have

```
var aService : AdService?

//aService is initialised

//COMPILER ERROR: Binary operator ’==’ cannot be applied to two AdServiceType operands
if aService!.serviceType == Normal {
   //DO SOMETHING            
}
```

I got the compiler error mentioned above when I check if `serviceType` is `Normal`. Why? How to get rid of it?

Comment: That should be implemented as an `enum` instead. Now, you can either compare `serviceType.value` or conform to `Equatable` protocol and provide a custom comparison logic in order to use `==` on `AdServiceType`

Comment: @iosDev82 I was sceptical about this but yes I think it makes sense after all, so I've marked it. Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the simplest solution is to compare the value of `struct` 's property:

```
if aService!.serviceType.value == Normal.value {
   //DO SOMETHING.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The `AdServiceType` struct is not `Equatable` and cannot be used as a switch expression. But its `value` can. Try:

```
switch aService!.serviceType.value {
case Internal.value:
   //do something
case Normal.value:
   //do something
case External.value:
  //do something
default:
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can extend `AdServiceType` adding support for the `Equatable` protocol:

```
extension AdServiceType : Equatable {}
public func ==(lhs: AdServiceType, rhs: AdServiceType) -> Bool
{
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
}
```

and leave the switch as it is.

Comment: I used the value, and got ERROR: Binary operator '~=' cannot be applied to 'AdServiceType' and 'UInt'

Comment: Did you use value everywhere? On the switch line and on all the case lines?

Comment: Oh, I only used in switch line. Thanks! It is fine now!

Answer (score 4):

I would fix it by making the struct Equatable:

```
extension AdServiceType: Equatable {}

func ==(lhs: AdServiceType, rhs: AdServiceType) -> Bool {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know swift but as far as i can understand
Your struct is service type which is an object of type AdService>
I think u need to get the variable inside the struct to make that operation as to giving an example

```
myStruct{
int x
int y
}
```

Now the condition would be valid for

```
myStruct obj1;
obj1.x = 50;
obj2.y = 40;
```

`if(obj.x == obj.y)`
Something like this. You got to access the value inside the struct, not the struct itself. Or rather assign an `&&` operator for
`(struct.x == struct2.x && struct.y == struct2.y)` would pretty much represent `values of struct == values of some other struct`

Answer (score -2):

I do not have a lot of knowledge about your Thirdparty framework. But I know some types do not use '==' but .equals. For example:

```
if aService!.serviceType.equals(Normal)
```

Maybe that should do it.

Answer (score -3):

Just change it into class and nsobject and be over with the pain.

```
class MyClass: NSObject {

    //Write code in here
}
```

Comment: Totally disagree, one of the strengths of swift is value types with structs, you should check out 'Building Better Apps with Value Types in Swift' (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-414/)

Comment: if I am not going to be able to use == easily, then there is not much point. You also miss out of all the other NSObject utility functions too .

Comment: If you are going to use Swift, you might as well write idiomatic code when you can..